# Use VLC Plugin in HTA

Tags: activex, vlc, hta, trusted-sites

As I've noticed, the VLC plugin works in  HTA window.

The issue is, I can get it working on multiple machines that already have VLC installed, but when it comes to a one that doesn't, the fallback (axvlc.cab) won't run because of this error:

> Windows has blocked this software because it can’t verify the
>   publisher

After looking online, I found that you can change the Trusted Sites settings to allow the plugin to load, but this doesn't seem to be making any difference. Any ideas?

My current code is as follows:

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="https://download.videolan.org/vlc/0.8.2/win32/axvlc.cab" id="vlc" events="True" width="609" height="343" style="outline: none; border: 0; -webkit-border:0 !important;">
    <param name="Src" value="mySrc"/>
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True"/>
    <param name="AutoLoop" value="False"/>
    <param name="AutoPlay" value="True"/>
    <embed id="vlcEmb" type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" target="mySrc" width="690" height="343"/>
</object>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code of the VLC plugin ?

Comment: @Hackoo Done. I've recently added the 'style' element to see if I could get rid of the black border on error, but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with embedded VLC Plugin video like this in HTA :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Embedded VLC Plugin video</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Embedded video"
  ID="Embedded video"
  ICON="nslookup.exe"
  WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
<style>
body {
color:white;
background-color:lightblue;
}
</style>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Sub Reload()
    window.location.reload(True)
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<BODY>
<center>
<br><hr>
<center>
<!-- MRL="http://incident.net/v8/files/mp4/3.mp4" -->
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="vlc" id ="vlc" autoplay="Yes" loop="no" width="850" height="420" MRL="rtsp://216.16.160.25:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264"></embed>
</center>
<br><hr>
<img src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/23/22961.png" Title="Reload Application video" alt="Reload Application video" onclick="Reload()" style="cursor:hand">
</center>
</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried the Embed, I also forgot the mention that my stream is RTSP.

Comment: Check my edit with RTSP example that i use it in the new code !

Comment: Hi, the Embed doesnt show anything at all. I've ended u hiding the VLC plugin if an error occurs, and removed the link to the VLC site so it doesnt try to download it if it doesnt already exist.